# Can a IOS keyboard extension access the keychain?

Tags: ios, swift, keychain, ios-app-extension

I am trying to share keychain data between my app and my custom IOS keyboard extension.

Whenever I try to access the keychain from the keyboard extension I get the error:

`OSStatus error:[-25291] No keychain is available. You may need to restart your computer.`

This is odd because I can access the keychain without any problems from the parent app. I was wondering if a IOS keyboard extension can even access the keychain of its parent app? or if it can even access the IOS keychain at all?

[I found this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127443/access-the-keychain-from-ios-keyboard-extension) but I am not sure if that is the answer since it does not once talk about keychain sharing and using entitlements etc....

Comment: [check here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH26-SW15)

Comment: What is the solution ? I am facing same issue on device.

Answer (score 0):

The IOS Keyboard can access a keychain if it enables keychain sharing with the parent app and also has `RequestsOpenAccess` set to `YES`